# Reusing Views when they are already assigned to the same element

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

In my app I'm displaying images on a grid view.  In some cases there are a a lot of images on a single grid view (up to 1,000).  This is driven off user data and is unavoidable.

It's impractical to load all images in memory. I tried that and was hitting memory errors fairly quickly.  So to avoid this I create [AsyncTasks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in the [getView() method of my array adaptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) which load the image in the background.  This works very smoothly so far.

The problem is that the set of images can change.  `notifyDataSetChanged()` will trigger `getView()` to be called on every item on screen.  **The result is a lot of CPU time spent re-loading images which don't need to be changed.**

Is there any way to detect if `getView()` is "reusing" a view to display the same element as it's already displaying?  Alternatively is it possible to detect if an `ImageView` has already has a Bitmap assigned?

Comment: The second parameter of `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` should be the reused view

Comment: Why not use a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager`. This way you have `notifyItemChanged()` method to efficiently update only that item.

Comment: @VeneetReddy that looks to be the way to go thanks.   It seems to be screwing up my layout (everything's left aligned instead of center) but that's a separate question. Thanks